# What is the identification of the font being used for the Solaris console in text mode?

Tags: solaris, console, fonts

What is the identification of the font that is being used on Solaris for console text?

Is there a Windows equivalent?

See the example in the attached screenshot.

[image: solaris text console session]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I converted the font into a TTF file at some stage, which I have used on OS X with some success.  When rendered with anti-aliasing, it's usable at a surprisingly broad range of sizes.

It's available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210227104132/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zygo/xscreensaver/master/OSX/gallant12x22.ttf).

Answer (score 7):

The source code of this font (Sun Gallant Demi) is available [here](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/898c3fec4c1cbcd45754042f6635b76a9067abd6/usr/src/uts/common/font/12x22.c).

It is available (or a close equivalent) under Linux distributions under `/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/sun12x22.psfu.gz` and in FreeBSD with `allscreens_flags="-f gallant"` in `/etc/rc.conf`.

I have no doubt with conversion tools like `psf2bdf` and `Fontforge`, you'll be able to convert it to something usable under Windows.

Beware that the resulting font will have a fixed width so will only be usable at its own size, any other size would give an ugly text due to pixel interpolation.

Comment: Converting would be a fair amount of work (OP is likely looking for an existing font).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Depends on how you define a fair amount of work. With the both tools mentioned in my reply installed under Linux, that should take less than one minute.

Comment: On Windows, most people would expect a TrueType font.  Getting a usable (i.e., not ugly) TrueType font takes work.  If you've found something that eliminates the work, you might consider showing the results.

Comment: @ThomasDickey The Solaris console font is a fixed size font. It can be easily converted to a ttf file but the resulting font would only be useful if used at the proper size. The OP doesn't specifically ask for a scalable font but you are right it should be considered he expects one.

Answer (score 4):

According to Andrew Gabriel on a [Usenet thread in 2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.solaris.x86/e3bUj22fj6s):

```
In article <87y5c3j...@newsguy.com>,
- show quoted text -
I don't think you can. There's only one font built-in to the vgatext
driver which is 8x16, which gives standard size (80x24?) on 1024x768
VGA console.

I have a vague recollection it could be done with much older releases
of Solaris x86 which used the fonts stored in the VGA card (of which
there are several standard sizes), but now it loads Sun's workstation
font into the VGA card, and there's only one resolution of that
included in the x86 driver.

BTW, the font is a bitmap font called Sun Gallant Demi, or in X,
-sun-gallant-demi-*-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

So in theory you could run:

xterm -font '-sun-gallant-demi-*-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' -fg white -bg black

to run an xterm looking like the console, except Solaris 11 no longer
includes the Sun fonts. You may be able to extract them from an
older release or find them somewhere on the web.

-- 
Andrew Gabriel
[email address is not usable -- followup in the newsgroup]
```

Given the **`sun`** in the font name, it's unlikely that you'll get exactly that font with Windows.